Using a child URL as a query param to a parent page
I'd like to set up a single page (/reviews-by-rating/) as a "parent" of several other pages (/reviews-by-rating/5-stars/, /reviews-by-rating/4-stars/, etc.).
I've created the reviews-by-rating page manually, and added some debugging code to it by way of a simple plugin.
When /reviews-by-rating/ is loaded, I'd like to display a paragraph of text, but when any of the child pages are loaded, I'd like to use the url fragment as a query param to dictate what content I load. In other words when /reviews-by-rating/5-stars/ is accessed I'd like WordPress to return the main page, with a query param of $rating (or something like that) in order to retrieve all reviews with 5 stars and display them, etc.
I'm comfortable working within WordPress code, I've written a number of plugins, but I'm not sure what this behavior would be called.
Could someone point me in the right direction? Also, I'm at the very beginning stages of this functionality, so if manually creating a page isn't the best approach, feel free to suggest better alternatives.
